# Django & WordPress - wp-admin redirect issue

Tags: django, wordpress, nginx, docker

I have some specific configuration. I have a django site, and want to add an exiting blog which powered by Wordpress into django subfolder.

For security reasons I didn't want to install php stack aside django, and runned it in docker. Both are served by nginx, django also has a uwsgi.

In the Wordpress admin I configured both site and wordpress urls like this: `https://mycoolsite.tld/blog`

So, everything works well, except of some hardcoded redirect from `https://mycoolsite.tld/blog/wp-admin` to `https://mycoolsite.tld/wp-admin`.

The question - how can I play with nginx locations (and not tweak wordpress if possible) for accessing the `/blog/wp-admin` url?

Related nginx configs:

**Django server  - nginx blog location**

```
location /blog/ {
    rewrite ^/blog/(.*)$ /$1 break;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080; # localhost(8080) <--> docker(80)
    proxy_redirect off;
}
```

**Wordpress nginx config (inside docker)**:

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;

root /var/www/wordpress;
index index.php index.html index.htm;


location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
error_page 404 /404.html;
error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

}

Comment: why do you need two nginx configurations?

Comment: one is serving django on the host server, second is serving wordpress inside docker.

Comment: So you are having the one nginx which passes requests either to another nginx instance or to a wsgi server such as gunicorn?

Comment: one nginx (location /blog/) passes to another (proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;), the question - how to handle /blog/wp-admin with nginx locations.